# Correct bounds for simple triple integral in rectangular coordinates?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

This is homework, so I am not after a solution to this problem.

> I am required to evaluate the integral $\iiint_{V}y\;dV$. $V$ here is the solid bounded above by the plane $x+y+z=1$  and by the region in the $xy$-plane bounded by the curves $y=1$, $x=0$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$.

I am just after clarification on my bounds. I firstly went ahead and said my bounds would be
\begin{align*}
0\leq\;& z\leq1-x-y\\
\sqrt{x}\leq\;&y\leq1\\
0\leq\;& x\leq1
\end{align*}
I did this by just thinking "I'll do $z$ first, and then I can sketch the region in the $xy$-plane to work out my remaining bounds and to satisfy my chosen order of integration of $dzdydx$."

I left it and now I've revisited it to double check my working, and I did a quick sketch of the whole lot this time (see below - apologies for dodgy sketching skills)

[image]

It seems to me that my original bounds were **incorrect**. By inspecting the sketch here, I want to adjust my bounds to
\begin{align*}
0\leq\;& z\leq1-x-y\\
\sqrt{x}\leq\;&y\leq1-x\\
0\leq\;& x\leq\text{the intersection of }\sqrt{x}\text{ and }1-x\;\left(=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

I'm just after clarification on how to determine bounds. Once I've got bounds, I can perform the integral no sweat. Is my second attempt correct? Or my first attempt? If not, why and what am I not understanding correctly?

Thank you all for your time - I know this is an elementary question!

Comment: I would ask for clarification from the teacher who gave you that homework problem. It's unclear (to me at least) exactly what solid is intended. Are you quoting the exact phrasing of the problem?

Comment: @HansLundmark Sorry, that's me trying to paraphrase. Naughty me. The exact phrasing is "Evaluate the integral $\iiint_{V}y\;dV$, where $V$ is the solid lying below the plane $x+y+z=1$ and above the region in the $xy$-plane bounded by the curves $y=1$, $x=0$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$."

Comment: OK, in that case your second attempt seems fine. Those values of $(x,y)$ for which the plane $z =1-x-y$ goes *below* the $xy$-plane must be excluded, just like you have done in your sketch (which isn't bad at all, by the way!).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your time @HansLundmark. Much appreciated.